# VB hyper Reference

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

I've written the code below but it does not work. Can someone point out the mistake for me?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_click()
   If Slide1.m.Text = g Then
      ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 3
   ElseIf Slide1.m.Text = h Then
     ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 4
   Else
     ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 1
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it "does not work"?

Comment: What's in `g` and `h`?

Comment: If you are checking for text equal to "g" or "h" then try: `Slide1.m.Text = "g"` and `Slide1.m.Text = "h"`.

Comment: What does "Slide1.m.Text" mean? Is Slide1 a variable holding a reference to slide 1 in the presentation? Is m the name of a shape on slide 1?  If so, what sort of shape?

Comment: That is not VB.NET code.  It  VB6 or a variant (like VBA)

Comment: @ƉiamondǤeezeƦ , TY so much.. I already learnt a lot of languages including Q-BASIC.. But then, i forgot the quotes.. People can be noobs. TY for your time..

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above, you are missing quote marks in the `if` statements.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_click()
   If Slide1.m.Text = "g" Then
      ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 3
   ElseIf Slide1.m.Text = "h" Then
     ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 4
   Else
     ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 1
   End If
End Sub
```